# Is there a Java Library for Collection Processing?

Tags: java, exception, collections

I have to run through a Collection of 150,000+ items once a month, and with everything that happens it takes roughly 3 to 4 hours which is fine. The problem is that sometimes some of the data throws an `exception` (which of course didn't happen on my first test run until like item 148,000).  I simply set it to logically ignore the exception (logging it of course), but I realized I don't always want to simply ignore the exception.

I wrote a simply exception handler that dealt with different types of exceptions and what to do if a certain type happens; for example, if I get a `SQLException` I abort the process, but on an `NullPointerException` I continue since this is usually a problem with the data. I also track the total number of exceptions and if I hit a preset limit, I also kill the process.

So my question is: I will be building more of the these programs for dealing with different types of data in `Collections`. Is there a library that deals with collections and dealing with different types of exceptions?

Below is some code I added per a comment request. If you are thinking to yourself, "Well, that does what you want it to do, what is the problem?", you are right.  But I was wondering if there was a library that existed that let me register exceptions and what to do when encountered. For example, I want to stop processing when exceptions of type A or D occur, continue when B occurs unless it happens X number of times, continue when C occurs unless it happens Y number of times, and completely ignore E. Mainly because I know I have different datasets and `collections` I and others will be working with in the future and want something consistent to use.

Basic Code Snippet:

```
exeptionLimit = 50;
exceptionCount = 0;
for (long id : MyCollection)
{
     try
     {
         //All these methods throw the exceptions 
         Item item = getItemById(id);
         NewData data = ProcessItem(item);
         SaveNewData(data);
     }
     catch (SQLException e)
     {
         //log

         throw e; //I want this to cause the process to fail
     }
     catch (NullPointerException e)
     {
          //log
          exceptionCount++;
          if (exceptionCount >= exceptionLimit) throw new Exception("Limit hit!");
     }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell if your code would benefit from some library. Could you post some code that demonstrates how you process your data?

Answer (score 3):

A `Collection` represent a logical grouping of data and a set of functions to operate on the data.
You can find libraries that offer advanced data-structures and better performance than what is offered in the `JDK` but if I understand your question correctly, what you need is something to understand the logic you want to build *on top* of the collection.
I mean, the separation between different types of exceptions and if they are logged or not etc. are part of *your* application logic.
It is not something related to a collections framework which offers exactly that.  Collections and helper methods *on data*

Comment: That's correct; the collection really doesn't have anything to do with the exceptions, maybe I should have used the term `Iterator` instead, as I am more dealing with what happens during an iteration of a `collection`. Sometimes it's hard to ask the right question until you hear some of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up cobbling together my own solution, but recently stumbled upon the Asynchronous retry pattern:

https://github.com/nurkiewicz/async-retry

And a good article about it:

http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2013/07/asynchronous-retry-pattern.html